# How do I use regex to match a datetime string that contains space, null, and newline chars?

Tags: c, regex

I'm iterating through a file using `fgets` and I'm trying to see if a line matches certain criteria.

Basically, my loop is

```
#define BUFSIZE = 4096;

FILE *txt_file = fopen("some_file.txt", "r");
char buffer[BUFSIZE] = {'\0'};
int i;
while (fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, txt_file)){
    //some logic

    // Reset buffer string
    for (i=0; i<BUFSIZE; i++)
        buffer[i] = '\0';
}
```

I have various datetime strings that can take the form of:

- `yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss`
- `yyyy-d-mm hh:mm:ss`
- `yyyy-dd-m hh:mm:ss` `
- `yyyy-d-m hh:mm:ss`

However, the datetime strings may or may not be preceded by whitespaces, and they will have null chars (the `\0` char I mean) because of the way I'm using `buffer`.

I'm using the following regular expression to match one of the above forms:

```
.*\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]).*
```

(The hh:mm:ss part doesn't matter.) If I put it into a format that C can interpret,

```
char *regex_str = ".*\\d{4}\\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]).*"
```

The problem is that I keep getting `No Match` when I attempt to find a match. Basically within my `while` loop, I'm trying:

```
int reti = regcomp(&regex, regex_str, REG_EXTENDED);
if (reti)
    fprintf(stderr, "could not compile regex\n");

reti = regexec(&regex, buffer, 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti){
    char msgbuf[100];
    regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
    fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
}
```

The regex compiles for me, but it's just not finding anything. I know that there are null chars and a newline char. I tried adding `x00+` to check for null chars and `(\r\n|\r|\n)` to check for a new line, but I'm not having any success. What am I doing wrong with my regular expression? I used https://www.regextester.com/ and my regex works there, but not in C.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping the month and day

```
".*\\d{4}-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012]).*"
```

===============

```
 .* 
 \d{4} 
 -
 (                             # (1 start), Day
      0? [1-9] 
   |  
      [12] [0-9] 
   |  
      3 [01] 
 )                             # (1 end)
 -
 (                             # (2 start), Month
      0? [1-9] 
   |  
      1 [012] 
 )                             # (2 end)
 .*
```

Answer (score 0):

> a datetime string that contains space, null …

A C string by definition cannot contain null characters except for the terminating `'\0'`.

> it's just not finding anything

It seems that you misinterpret the return value of `regexec()` - you print an error message `if (!reti)`, but *`regexec()` returns zero for a successful match*.